# Get results between specific date range

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, api, mongoose

I'm creating a API with node js and mongoose. I have saved my data successfully.

```
const salesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userID: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    total: {
        type: String
    },
    saletime: {
        type: Date
    }
});
```

**This is the schema I used to store data**

Now the thing is I want to retrieve only the results of one week 
I used the following code to do it but it says

***Error: Can't use gte with Date***

How can I retrieve only the results of last week ??

```
router.post('/getmyweeksales', async(req, res) => {

    function remDays(date, days) {
        var result = new Date(date);
        result.setDate(result.getDate() - days);
        return result;
    }

    const verified = jwt.verify(req.body.token, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET);
    const date = req.body.currentdate;


    const sales = await Sale.find({
        userID: verified._id,
        saletime: { "gte": remDays(date, 7), "$lt": Date(date) }
    }).sort({ saletime: -1 });

    res.send(sales);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo! I think you forgot the `$` in `$gte`. Try changing it to

```
saletime: { "$gte": remDays(date, 7), "$lt": Date(date) }
```